# intersections package does not find second point of intersection of a circle and an ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to find the intersection of two paths, a circle and an ellipse.
Only one intersection is found. Why? Thanks.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes, intersections}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  \def\R{3cm}
  \def\c1{(O) circle (\R)}
  \fill[ball color=white!10, opacity=0.3, name path=c1] \c1;
  \draw[rotate=42, name path=c3, yscale=0.5, color=red] \c1;
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c3, by={c131, c132}}];
  \node[] at (c131) {c131};
  \node[] at (c132) {c132};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here the graph:

[image: intersection package finds only one point]

To expand a bit. It finds intersections in many cases but not in this.
Here is my complete code so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes, pgfplots.external, intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  \def\R{3cm}

  %outside sphere
  \def\c1{(O) circle (\R)}
  \fill[ball color=white!10, opacity=0.3, name path=c1] \c1;


  %one lune side
  \draw[rotate=96, name path=c2, yscale=0.5] \c1;
  %the other lune side
  \draw[rotate=42, name path=c3, yscale=0.5, color=red] \c1;

  % find intersections of each lune side with outside circle
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c2, 
           by={c121, c122}}];

  % perhaps a bug in intersections but I need to reverse the sign of c123
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c3, 
           by={c131, c132}}];

  % find intersections between c2 and c3
  \path [name intersections={of=c2 and c3, 
           by={c231, c232, c233, c234}}];


  % Locate points (a preview) uncomment the following lines
  % to better understand the figure
   \node[] at (c121) {c121};
   \node[] at (c122) {c122};
   \node[] at (c131) {c131};
   \node[] at (c132) {c132};
   \node[] at (c231) {c231};
   \node[] at (c232) {c232};
   \node[] at (c233) {c233};
   \node[] at (c234) {c234};


  \path[name path=c4, yscale=0.25 , rotate=42] \c1;
\end{tikzpicture}


 \end{document}
```

and here my figure:
[image: Found 7 of 8 points]

Why does it find all the intersections in the other couple of ellipses and not in the points c131, c132?

Comment: You can't say `\def\c1{...}` or, rather, you can't say this to mean what you want. The number is not allowed unless you change the cat codes or it is a single character command.

Comment: @cfr : I will add more information to the question in a minute.

Comment: There are an infinite number of intersections. You've only named the first two. I think. Remember that the calculations are not going to be very exact as this is TeX. Mathematically, there may be only 2. But that assumes precision. Depending on the details, I think you are or are not getting infinite numbers. The rotation is affecting the distinctness of the paths at the relevant places. This is just a guess.

Comment: `\def\c1` does not define a macro with the name `c1` which is, I think, what you believe it is doing. It defines a macro `\c` which must always be followed by `1`, which is entirely pointless. `\newcommand*`  is much safer here anyway and should always be preferred in LaTeX. (Isn't always possible, of course. But it is here.)

Comment: Right now, you are overwriting the definition of `\c`. This is not at all wise. It means that e.g. `\c a` will give an error. If you used `\newcommand*` you'd get some sort of error or warning. `\def` won't complain - it just redefines `\c` regardless of the fact that it is a basic, standard command.

Comment: @cfr : There are only two intersections. We are in 2D and two ellipses (circle or not) intersect at most at 4 points.  You might be right about the macro. I will remove all macros from the program and see if works.

Comment: I am right about the macro. Try leaving it and typing `\c a` (a̧). With your `\def`, you will get an error instead of a̧. About the intersections: I'm not disputing the maths. I'm suggesting that that may not be how it looks with the imprecise nature of the calculations i.e. it may look to TikZ as if the lines coincide for a little, yielding infinite intersections. Doesn't it seem strange to you that TeX takes such a long time to compile it? And that if you add additional names (c133,c134) etc., they get defined, too? I just think you are expecting more precision than you are getting.

Comment: @cfr : you are wrong about the macro. I removed all the macros and the result is the same. Why do not you try yourself before wasting my time? \fill[ball color=white!10, opacity=0.3, name path=c1] (O) circle (\R);

Comment: @cfr : solve it and post it please.

Comment: OK. I will put you on my blacklist. I am ***not*** wasting your time. I never ***said*** that the macro caused this problem. I told you how to test to confirm for yourself that `\def\c1` overwrites the standard `\c` command. `\def\c1` is wrong. It is not the cause of this problem.  I know this because I tested it. I still commented to explain that it is wrong. I certainly should not have wasted ***my*** time. It is your problem, after all. If I do find a solution, be sure that I will not make the mistake of posting it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the intersection of two ellipses (one of them could be a circle) has 4 points (no two).  For some reason three points are up and one is down (I expected two up and two down, but I do not care about this at this point). 
Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3d,shapes, pgfplots.external, intersections}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[]
  \coordinate (O) at (0,0);

  \def\R{3cm}

  %outside sphere
  \def\c1{(O) circle (\R)}
  \fill[ball color=white!10, opacity=0.3, name path=c1] \c1;


  %one lune side
  \draw[rotate=96, name path=c2, yscale=0.5] \c1;
  %the other lune side
  \draw[rotate=42, name path=c3, yscale=0.5, color=red] \c1;

  % find intersections of each lune side with outside circle
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c2, 
           by={c121, c122}}];

  % perhaps a bug in intersections but I need to reverse the sign of c123
  \path [name intersections={of=c1 and c3, 
           by={c131, c132,c133,c134}}];

  % find intersections between c2 and c3
  \path [name intersections={of=c2 and c3, 
           by={c231, c232, c233, c234}}];


  % Locate points (a preview) uncomment the following lines
  % to better understand the figure
   \node[] at (c121) {c121};
   \node[] at (c122) {c122};
   \node[] at (c131) {c131};
   \node[] at (c132) {c132};
   \node[] at (c133) {c133};
   \node[] at (c134) {c134};
   \node[] at (c231) {c231};
   \node[] at (c232) {c232};
   \node[] at (c233) {c233};
   \node[] at (c234) {c234};


  \path[name path=c4, yscale=0.25 , rotate=42] \c1;
\end{tikzpicture}


 \end{document}
```

Here is the figure:

[image: intersection points]

Comment: The problem is that you are looking at two *unstable* intersections. If you enlarge the ellipse by a factor of  1.0000000001, the two intersections become four; if you shrink the ellipse by a factor of 0.999999999999, the two intersections become zero. In a situation like this, you should never rely on finite-precision computer calculations (such as those performed by TikZ) to get it right.

Comment: @CharlesStaats  I agree with you. Unfortunately this type of intersections is quite common, specially for anything in the field of spherical geometry where you have to differentiate between what is in the front or what is in the back of a sphere. Yes, TikZ is not reliable for this level of precision, hence we should print labels to know what is what and then after that choose (by trial an error, which is not painful since the number of intersections is small) the one that works for the figure to look right.